# Cassandra Exception in thread Thread[FlushWriter:1,5,main]

Tags: cassandra

When I start Cassandra 2.0.3 server , I suddenly start getting error given below, I deleted the 'data' folder but still getting same error. Please help

```
INFO 17:21:08,084 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-local@15628573(149/1490 serialized/live bytes, 6 ops)

 INFO 17:21:08,087 Writing Memtable-local@15628573(149/1490 serialized/live bytes, 6 ops)
ERROR 17:21:08,121 Exception in thread Thread[FlushWriter:1,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: Memory was freed
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory.checkPosition(Memory.java:146)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory.setMemory(Memory.java:60)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.obs.OffHeapBitSet.clear(OffHeapBitSet.java:98)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.obs.OffHeapBitSet.<init>(OffHeapBitSet.java:52)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FilterFactory.createFilter(FilterFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FilterFactory.getFilter(FilterFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter$IndexWriter.<init>(SSTableWriter.java:418)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.<init>(SSTableWriter.java:102)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.createFlushWriter(Memtable.java:395)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:337)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runWith(Memtable.java:320)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareRunnable.java:48)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```